# How to win the rebellion in Poland 1066?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm playing as Poland at the beginning of CK2 without the *Old gods expansion* so 1066. A rebellion starts in Poland at the beginning of the game or 1 or 2 years after. What is the best way to successfully win the rebellion without screwing up vital battles. Or is there anyway of preventing the rebellion?

Comment: Who is rebelling and what are their demands? This is not a scripted event; it's caused by your vassals' opinion modifiers.

Comment: It's not scripted but the game starts of having one of the vassals thinking he's a better ruler then me

Comment: Your brother in Mazovia, you mean?

Comment: Yeah, my brother in Mazovia and a vassle who has land above krakow.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the war? I ask because your question doesn't mention any particular difficulties you're asking for help solving. War is a great way to eliminate your brother and consolidate power, so if you're not having trouble with it, the war is to your benefit!

Comment: Wait sorry no. This is a civil war. I have a rebellion in Poland by the the North East and North West of Poland,

Comment: Yes, civil war. Crushing a rebellious vassal lets you imprison and take a title from them, which is a great way to start fixing Poland's weak king in 1066. What *specific* troubles are you having winning the civil war?

Comment: Well him and the other vassal have bigger man power then me. Now my king is a great general, but it isn't enough. I am new to the game so I might be missing something.

Comment: How are you judging that? You should have two dukes to raise levies from still—are you counting them?

Comment: Emm yes all together I still had a couple of thousand less then them put together.

Comment: Put one of them in jail. If he rebels take him down on his own (easier than all of the rebels together) and if he doesn't he can't cause much trouble in jail. Downside is that you will get tyranny opinion modifiers.

Comment: SMeznaric provides and interesting option. Starting a game like this is often called a Reign of Terror and it's usually recommended you go all or nothing. If you imprison everyone, no one causes trouble. If you imprison one or two, everyone else tends to cause trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately boost the opinion of the two dukes beneath you as much as possible, via gifts, appointing them to positions, etc. This will cause them to give you a greater percentage of levies, which should be enough to win you the war. That is the most direct method prior to the war.
Since your tech is equal and you have a better general, this should be enough to ensure you win battles as long as you don't screw up and damage your morale or attack at a serious penalty.